# DirectAccess & VPN on Windows Server 2012 Essentials

Tags: vpn, direct-access, windows-server-essentials, essentials-2012-r2

This is supposed to be very simple - deploy WS2012E on server, install the DirectAccess and VPN role and that should be about it.

But it seems that its not, tried this method with no success,
Not just that, it also made something that prevented new clients from connecting to the network using the Connector (Server not found issues, even tough on the first screen [find server] it found the server and connected, on the second screen it just took like 5-10 min and then returned with the "not found").

So, i reinstalled the whole server after two days of trying to fix the issues.

Now,
The server is the Domain Controller,
from what i read in some places, the domain controller cannot serve as the DirectAccess,
on others, it can.

Can someone help me in directing me to a working Deployment/Setup for DirectAccess?

If another server is needed, can it be virtualized on the Domain Controller?

If its not needed, What is the correct way to setup it?

Comment: -1 with no comment. thx, you're really helpful.

Comment: Most likely it is because you've basically asked "Can someone walk me through DirectAccess from start-to-finish" which is a fairly broad question to ask. You also state that you've found contradictory information about where DA can be installed. You should be looking on TechNet and nowhere else for this - as TechNet is Microsoft's official documentation library. Don't take someone else's word for it.

Comment: i have already read the first 3 pages on google (the results that is), including the TechNet and tried everything suggested, but still cant get it to work. In the question i said `Can someone help me in directing me to a working Deployment/Setup for DirectAccess?` never asked anyone to write here the complete answer, just to direct me to some article that they followed/know about which has the information i am looking for.

Comment: You're straddling the line and leaning more towards a "learning material recommendation" which is OT here.  You have enough rep, why not modify your question with what is actually wrong (errors, screenshots, configuration details) and then let someone assist you in fixing those errors? -- http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply looking for an authoritative source of information about Direct Access, you're going to want to read all of the information available on the [TechNet Remote Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/dd420463.aspx) documentation page. Not all of it pertains to Direct Access, but the information that does is complete and official.

Comment: Thank you. I read only the DirectAccess part.
But i will follow your advice and read the whole thing.